# Android: listview not working, Images are changing when scrollling the list

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app i have a listAdapter where iam loading the phonenumbers and their images from phonebook, as follows

```
 public ProfileAdapter(Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, List<Profile> listCont,int renderer, String profileType) {
        super(activity, textViewResourceId, listCont);
        this.renderer = renderer;
        this.listCont = listCont;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.profileType=profileType;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        View rowView;
        public TextView textEmailId;
        public TextView textContNo;
        public TextView text;
        public QuickContactBadge photo;
        public ViewHolder(View view)
        {
             rowView = view;
        }
        public TextView getTextView()
        {
             if(text ==null)
                   text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
             return text;
        }
        public TextView getTextView1()
        {
             if(textContNo ==null)
                 textContNo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contactno);
             return textContNo;
        }
        public TextView getTextView2()
        {
             if(textEmailId ==null)
                 textEmailId = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.emailId);
             return textEmailId;
        }
        public QuickContactBadge getQuickContactBadge()
        {
             if(photo ==null)
                 photo = (QuickContactBadge) rowView.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);
             return photo;
        }

    }


    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

    View view = convertView; 
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) (getContext() 
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)); 
    view = inflater.inflate(renderer, null); 

    holder = new ViewHolder(view);

 holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name); 
 holder.textContNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactno); 
 holder.textEmailId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailId);  
 holder.photo = (QuickContactBadge ) view.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);

 view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder =(ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

 Profile contact = listCont.get(position); 
    holder.text.setText(contact.getName()); 

    QuickContactBadge photo = (QuickContactBadge ) view.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);  
    photo.setTag(contact.getMobileNo()); 
    new LoadImage(photo).execute(contact.getMobileNo()); 

    contact.getName(); 
    contact.getId(); 
        holder.textContNo.setText(contact.getNumber());
        holder.textEmailId.setText(contact.getEmail());
        return view;
    }
```

and iam loading the images using the asynctask as below

```
  class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{ 

        private QuickContactBadge qcb; 

        public LoadImage(QuickContactBadge qcb) { 
        this.qcb= qcb; 
        } 
        @Override 
        protected Bitmap doInBackground( final String... params) { 
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
        new QuickContactHelper(activity, qcb, (String) params[0]).addThumbnail(); 
        } 
        }); 
        return null; 
        } 
        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) { 

        }
```

iam facing the problem while scrolling the list view each time i scroll iam the images are changing for each contact, also scrolling is not smooth. i dnt know what am i doing wrong in code .Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's running very slow because you're not executing anything on the background thread.

```
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
    new QuickContactHelper(activity, qcb, (String) params[0]).addThumbnail(); 
    } 
    });
```

you're just asking to re-execute back on the UI thread.

The image keeps changing because it shows the image that was before you scroll, and after that process completes it puts the new image. You should on the getView put some blank image or image placeholder so it will be blank, then the image.

Also try do some caching. Check the LruCache.

**edit:**

I've never worked with the QuickContactBadge before I'll write how I would do code for ImageView and you can change the necessary parts.
inside the getView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // all that processing to get the data then...
   img.setImageResource(R.id.blank_user); // put something image placeholder (blank)
   new LoadImage(img).execute(url); // download

}
```

Comment: can u elaborate "getView put some blank image or image placeholder so it will be blank"?

Comment: I edited the post with an example. I've never worked with `QuickContactBadge` so I wrote the code as if it was for ImageView, you change the necessary bits. And seriously look into caching stuff

Comment: @never tried caching stuff...iam not downloadin this images from server, getting from the device itself still do i need to cache?..can u suggest me some links to get start.. thank you

Comment: thanks a lot , missed this  single line of code  img.setImageResource(R.id.blank_user);  and struggled for two days..finally it seems to work

Comment: ..hey as u said its running on Ui thread (activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable())...how to make it run in the background? any suggestions plz

Comment: @budius..one more issue, when the app starts first the images are repeating after scroling only they are getting stable?..any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try set `null` value to `ImageView`,

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   img.setImageResource(null); 
   new LoadImage(img).execute(url); 

}
```

it works for me..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend u to have a look at this blog : https://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/07/22/recycling-listview-rows/

the core code is here:

```
theListView.setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerListener() {
@Override
public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
    // Cast the view to the type of the view we inflated.
    MyCustomListRow row = (MyCustomListRow) view;

    // Get the view that holds the image and nullify the drawable.
    // GC will take care of cleaning up the memory used.
    row.getThatImageDrawableView().setImageDrawable(null);
}});
```